# combine result and separate by comma

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  tud.detail_company_name AS company_name,
  tud.detail_country AS company_country,
  trv.review_title AS review_title
FROM users_detail tud
INNER JOIN users_auth tua
  ON tud.user_id = tua.user_id
LEFT JOIN reviews trv
  ON tud.user_id = trv.review_company_id
WHERE
  tua.auth_user_type = "company" OR tua.auth_user_type = "guestcompany"
```

The query works fine, and it return results like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => The Coffee Brewery
            [company_country] => US
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Crea Nail Art Studio
            [company_country] => SG
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Fake goods!
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Never buy in there!
        )
)
```

As you noticed array key 2 & 3 has the same **company_name** but different **review_title**. Is there any possibility that it must be joined in one result and separated by comma? Say for example this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => The Coffee Brewery
            [company_country] => US
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Crea Nail Art Studio
            [company_country] => SG
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Fake goods!, Never buy in there!
        )
)
```

**EDIT**

What if the response is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => The Coffee Brewery
            [company_country] => US
            [review_title] => 
            [review_approved] =>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Crea Nail Art Studio
            [company_country] => SG
            [review_title] => 
            [review_approved] =>
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Fake goods!
            [review_approved] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Never buy in there!
            [review_approved] => 0
        )
)
```

How can I not include **0 review_approved** on the **review_title** `GROUP_CONCAT`? So it will output like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => The Coffee Brewery
            [company_country] => US
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Crea Nail Art Studio
            [company_country] => SG
            [review_title] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_name] => Hello Mall
            [company_country] => JP
            [review_title] => Fake goods!
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
  tud.detail_company_name AS company_name,
  tud.detail_country AS company_country,
  GROUP_CONCAT(trv.review_title SEPARATOR ',') AS review_titles
FROM users_detail tud
INNER JOIN users_auth tua
  ON tud.user_id = tua.user_id
LEFT JOIN reviews trv
  ON tud.user_id = trv.review_company_id
WHERE
  tua.auth_user_type = :company OR tua.auth_user_type = :guestcompany
GROUP BY 
    tud.detail_company_name,
    tud.detail_country;
```

Comment: Great! One question : Why does `tud.detail_company_name` & `tud.detail_country` is in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia - Thats how the `GROUP BY` clause works. Any columns that are not included in the `GROUP BY`, should be in an aggregate function. You can't include columns in the select clause that are not included in an aggregate function nor in the `GROUP BY` clause. You can do this in MySQL, indeed. But this is not recommended.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however, please see my edit. Huge thanks @Mahmoud Gamal.

Comment: In the JOIN, use `LEFT JOIN reviews trv
  ON ( tud.user_id = trv.review_company_id AND trv.review_approved <> 0 )`

Comment: @Akash - Thanks for the feedback. Which join by the way?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia the last one, `reviews trv`, I have edited my comment above

Comment: @Akash - Thanks, this should be your answer.